# Cakephp component error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, components

I have this component in my app:

```
class ImageComponent extends Component {


var $image;
var $image_type;

function __construct($filename = null){
    if(!empty($filename)){
        $this->load($filename);
    }
}

function load($filename) {
    $image_info = getimagesize($filename); //<<== LINE OF THE ERROR
    $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
    if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
        $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("The file you're trying to open is not supported");
    }

}
}
```

But, when I just load the component, I recieve this error:

```
 getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given [APP/Controller/Component/ImageComponent.php, line 33]
```

Thanks

Comment: [`Component::__construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array())`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#Component::__construct)

Answer (score 0):

the constructor of a component expects the first parameter to be a ComponentCollection object. on a side note - it's a code smell to change the param type of your parent's class function

Comment: Can i just delete the constructor?

Comment: dont do that. when something doesnt fit in your implementation, you should rethink your design pattern